# Kotlin --> Unresolved reference: submitButton

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I'm starting with Kotlin.
I have defined a button but if I try to use submitButton it immediately gives me the error "Unresolved reference: submitButton"
The code is as follows and it is not complete because I stopped when the error appeared and the submitButton turned red

```
package com.andreatom.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val continuaBTN = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnContinua)
            submitButton


    }
}
```

I didn't do anything because I had already used submitButton in other projects without problems and I can't choose among the suggestions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWLTL.png)